# Wrongly shifted second axis when axes were switched; ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was creating a plot with 2 y-axis where I combined line and column graphs.
This way, it looked the way it's supposed to be:

```
#definition of dummy data set
set.seed(1)
n<-30
prec1 <-round(runif(n, min=0, max=4),0)
prec2 <-round(runif(n, min=0, max=0),0)
depth1 <- runif(n, min=-0.3, max=0)
depth2 <- runif(n, min=-0.1, max=0.1)
date  <- seq(1,n,1)
id <- c(rep("P-05",n), rep("PR-07",n))

dat <- data.frame("date" = c(date,date),
                 "id" = id,
                 "prec" = c(prec1,prec2),
                 "depth" = c(depth1,depth2))


#definition of axis limiters
ylim.prim <- c(0, 4) 
ylim.sec <- c(-0.3,0.1) 
b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
a <- b*(ylim.prim[1] - ylim.sec[1])

ggplot()+
  geom_col(data=dat,aes(x=date,y=prec))+
  geom_line(data=dat,aes(x=date,y=a+depth*b,colour=factor(id)))+
  scale_y_continuous("precipitation",breaks=seq(0,4,by=0.5),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "depth",
                                         breaks=seq(-0.3,0.1,by=0.05),
                                         labels=comma))
```

[correct y-axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKwuJ.jpg)

BUT, when switching the y-left with y-right axis, the one axis shifts to the lower part of the plot.

Did I miss anything?

```
#definition of axis limiters
ylim.prim <- c(-0.3,0.1) 
ylim.sec <- c(0, 4) 
b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
a <- b*(ylim.prim[1] - ylim.sec[1])

ggplot()+
  geom_col(data=dat,aes(x=date,y=a+prec*b))+
  geom_line(data=dat,aes(x=date,y=depth,colour=factor(id)))+
  scale_y_continuous("depth",breaks=seq(-0.3,0.1,by=0.05),labels=comma,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "precipitation",
                                         breaks=seq(0,4,by=0.5)))
```

[wrong y-axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqefh.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question with the data you used (or a sample of it), which would allow others to reproduce your problem. A plot would also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added now how to create a dummy data set and example graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forgot to change the transformation in the second code. First code block

```
sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "depth",
```

Second code block

```
sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "precipitation",
```

but you changed the primary y-axis from `prec` to `a+prec*b`. So things are off.

If you simply want to switch sides, `scale_y_continuous` has an argument `position = "left"`, which you should be able to set to `"right"` (and I expect the secondary will appear to left automatically).

http://127.0.0.1:10092/library/ggplot2/html/scale_continuous.html

Comment: That was simple! Thank you!